# optim() not giving correct minima

Tags: r

I'm using `optim` to try and find the critical region in a binomial test, however after a certain sample size it fails to converge on the correct value.

Seems like the function is well behaved so not sure why it stops working at this point.

```
N <- 116

optim(1, function(x) abs(1 - pbinom(x, N, 0.1) - 0.05), method = "Brent", lower = 1, upper = N)
```

The `optim` function as above works for `N < 116`.

Comment: Not really an answer to your question,  but it works at least up to N=200 if you use `upper = N/2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient at your starting point is almost 0 and the algorithm cannot move to the next best solution.

One way is to use another starting point:

```
optim(0.1*N, function(x) abs(1 - pbinom(x, N, 0.1) - 0.05), method = "Brent", lower = 1, upper = N)
```

or to use `optimize` since its one dimensional:

```
optimize(function(x) abs(1 - pbinom(x, N, 0.1) - 0.05), c(1,N))
```

Comment: I'm afraid this answer is actually wrong: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591374/optim-method-brent-and-optimize-not-giving-correct-minimum-for-binomial-distri/69591643?noredirect=1#comment123007235_69591643

Comment: thanks @BenBolker, why is the gradient of the objective function exactly 0 at x=1?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably use the built-in `qbinom` function, which computes specified values of the quantile (inverse CDF) function for the binomial distribution: it works fine for any reasonable value of N.

```r
N <- 116
qbinom(0.95, size = N, prob = 0.1)
```

The function is *not* well-behaved from an optimization point of view: as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69591374/optim-method-brent-and-optimize-not-giving-correct-minimum-for-binomial-distri), it is piecewise constant.