# optim (method=Brent) and optimize not giving correct minimum for binomial distribution (N > 1000)

Tags: r

I'm using `optim()` (and `optimize()`) to try and find the the quantiles of a binomial distribution, however for N ~ 2000 (N = 2135), the functions do not give the correct value.

```r
optim(21, function(x) abs(1 - pbinom(x, 2135, 21/2135) - 0.1), 
      method = "Brent", lower = 1, upper = 2135) 

optimize(function(x) abs(1 - pbinom(x, 2135, 21/2135) - 0.1), c(1,2135))
```

P.S: I also try to set the `min` argument equal to the probability, but I still get incorrect answers.

Comment: Downvote because you don't make it clear at all what the issue is. What is correct? How do you know it's correct? Literally what is the issue? All questions that aren't answered here.

Comment: I do not know what is the correct result, otherwise I would not need to write a function to calculate the binomial quantiles. If you had run the above functions you would have noticed too that the output is not correct. The issue is pretty clear: I need to find the binomial quantiles by using an optimization procedure but the above solutions do not work.

Comment: Can you give more details about why you need to use an optimization procedure (and not e.g. the built-in `qbinom()` function)?  Is a root-finding procedure (as shown in my answer) acceptable?  If you really want to use an *optimization* procedure you will probably need to use something designed for *discrete* optimization.  I don't know much about these methods.

Comment: On `optim()`: it works with `L-BFGS-B` method and the # of defaults: `optim(116,function(x){abs(pbinom(x,1234,116/1234)-0.9)},gr = NULL,method = c('L-BFGS-B'), lower = 1, upper = 1234) #122.4819` but with the probability of defaults: `optim(116/1234,function(x){abs(pbinom(116,1234,x)-0.1)},gr = NULL,method = c('L-BFGS-B'), lower = 0, upper =1) #1`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, very useful. In general I do not want to use the `qbinom()` function simply because it uses the normal approximation. `uniroot()` is fine as well, thanks for suggesting

Comment: Are you sure the `qbinom()` function uses the normal approximation (only)? `?qbinom` says "‘qbinom’ uses the Cornish-Fisher Expansion to include a skewness correction to a normal approximation, **followed by a search**" (emphasis added); [this code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/1c47c2ea432eef9ede74bb73c1e521922399ed05/src/nmath/qDiscrete_search.h) is the discrete algorithm it uses.

Comment: @BenBolker indeed it's not really clear how `qbinom()` derives the quantile, it seems it uses normal approximation but not very clear to me what is "followed by a search". Regarding the `optim()` function (see comment above), I noticed that with the `L-BFGS-B` method, it gives the correct results if the argmin is the # default, while with the probability of defaults it fails. Do you have any clue for that ?

Comment: "followed by a search" means that it starts with an approximation but uses that as a basis for a search of the discrete space.  If you want to find the critical value it's by **far** the best idea to use `qbinom()` !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that `optimize()` assumes that small changes in the parameter will give reliable information about whether the minimum has been attained (and which direction to go if not). (I initially said that the function needed to be *differentiable*, which might not be true: see the [Wikipedia article on Brent's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brent%27s_method).) In other words, most of the easily available optimization algorithms can fail on an objective function that is *piecewise constant*, as this one is ...

IMO the accepted answer to this [nearly identical question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50400506/optim-not-giving-correct-minima?rq=1) is simply wrong. (It states that "the gradient at your starting point is almost 0", whereas in fact it's *exactly* zero; using `optimize()` doesn't help, as you found out, and picking a different starting point is more or less a matter of luck ...)

I made up a smaller example to illustrate: find the 0.6 quantile of the binomial distribution with N=10, prob=0.2. **R can do this directly, very easily: `qbinom(0.6, size=10, prob=0.2)` !** But assuming that you want to solve some other problem of a similar form, and this is just an example, or that the constraints are given by a homework problem, or ...

Slightly simplified objective function (using the squared difference rather than the absolute value):

```r
fx <- function(x) (pbinom(x, size=10, prob=0.2) - 0.6)^2
```

What does this look like?

```r
curve(fx, from = 0, to =10, n=501)
```

[image: step curve of objective function]

So the correct answer is any value between 2 and 3.  In this particular case `optimize(fx, interval=c(1,10))` happens to work OK (returns 2.313, you could use `floor()` to convert it to 2), but it will fail if I use a wider interval (`optimize(fx, interval=c(1,100))` returns 99.99996), or if I did a problem with a larger `size`.  Let me try

```r
fx2 <- function(x) pbinom(x, size=1000, prob=0.2) - 0.6
qbinom(0.6, size=1000, prob=0.2)  ## answer: 203
optimize(fx2, interval=c(1,1000)) ## 999.9999
```

The problem is that if the initial step of the optimization method jumps less than one unit, the algorithm will conclude that it has found the minimum.

One potential solution is to look for a *root* rather than a minimum:

```r
fx3 <- function(x) pbinom(x, size=1000, prob=0.2) - 0.6
uniroot(fx3, interval=c(1,1000)) ## 203
```

I don't know a *good* way to solve this as an optimization problem. A stochastic global optimizer would work, but would in general be very inefficient. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33122473/nonlinear-discrete-optimization-in-r) for one *particular* problem involving nonlinear discrete optimization in R. You can also look at the [optimization task view](https://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Optimization.html), although I didn't find it useful ...

Comment: Do you mean "stochastic global optimizer would work, but would in general *not* be very efficient"